# Json plus post plus curl in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Please don't close this question before read my actual problem. I have seen many related problems but I am still having. 
Simply I want to send a `json_encoded` array by `POST` method using `CURL` in PHP. When I set `content-type as application/json` the data is not posted. I receive empty `post` array. When I remove content-type line the data is posted but not as json.
Here is my code

```
 $data = array('id' => $post['id'], 'action' => $post['action']);
 $post_data = http_build_query($data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
```

I this case I receive empty post. If I comment out the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));` I will receive the post data but not json encoded. I want json_encoded array. Will any one tell me what am I doing wrong?

Best Regards:

Comment: Are you certain the target resource allows you to request the response format?

Comment: I am sending request to my other controller. How can I come to know that target resource allows or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding a query string to json not an array remove `$post_data = http_build_query($data);` and pass `$data` to json_encode.

```
 $data = array('id' => $post['id'], 'action' => $post['action']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

ofcourse for this to work the service nedds to support json posts.

Comment: When I remove `http_build_query($data)`, even then request is not posted. Empty post

Comment: What is meant by `the service nedds to support json posts.`? How can I come to know whether the supports or not?

Comment: @AwaisQarni use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)` to get the posted data.

Comment: If I want to check whether the posted data is json encoded or not? I am checking `if (is_object(json_decode($post)))` but now how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Try send-n-accept RAW POST request, via

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

[RAW POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)